# GoDaddy domain and Firebase hosting - not working

Tags: domains, web-hosting, godaddy, security-certificate

I hava a doamin name from **GoDaddy** , lets say - www.yoyo.com,
and I have a website hosting in **Firebase**, let say - yoyo-f1c2.firebase.com.

When I **Forward with Masking** I'm getting this error(chrome):

> Calling Element.createShadowRoot() for an element which already hosts
>   a shadow root is deprecated. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4668884095336448 for more
>   details.

and the **SSL certificate** that firebase supplies is gone.

However,
the website works well. and the domain name in the adress bar is the GoDaddy domain - www.yoyo.com. , witch is good - cuz this is what I wanted.

i checked the web but i cant find any guide on this aspect.

*if anyone knows how to make it work?*
 1. hosting on firebase with godaddy domain
 2. keeping the SSL certificate

Any help will be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by *When I Forward with Masking*. If you are using a GoDaddy *thing*, then that is very likely **not** recommended.

Comment: what do u recommend?

Comment: Creating a CNAME for www.yoyo.com to yoyo-f1c2.firebase.com. Without knowing more, this would be my first option.

Comment: thanks man. appreciate your help. tried it. not doing the trick. it cancel out the https.

Comment: Oh yeah. The certificate is for a specific URL. I am at a loss right now. I will have to think for a bit. I will up vote to help bring attention to your question.

Comment: Forwarding with masking will not work with SSL's since the forwarding is done at the web server level, and the certificate is installed for that server, not for the server you're forwarding too. You'll need to setup your DNS to point to the server the HTTPS is hosted on (Firebase). It's best if you work with GoDaddy's support team on these issues in the future.

Comment: https://medium.com/@hammad_tariq/firebase-web-hosting-and-connect-with-custom-godaddy-domain-tutorial-ae989c92368d